# Why time.sleep stops execution altogether?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following function is intended to run the loop for 20 minutes, processing SQL tasks if available. To avoid too much SQL calls when there is nothing to process, it is intended to sleep for 5 seconds before trying to process a task again:

```
def main():
    sql = 'some sql task here;'
    stop_time = datetime.today() + timedelta(minutes = 20)
    print('Started at ', datetime.now())
    print('Should stop at', stop_time)
    load_more_rows = True
    with ConnectionParameters.get_conn() as conn:
        while load_more_rows or (datetime.now() < stop_time):
            try:
                res = get_num_processed_batches(conn, sql)
                processed_batch = res > 0
            except Exception as ex:
                log_error(repr(ex))
                processed_batch = False
            if not processed_batch:
                print('Sleeping at ', datetime.now())
                time.sleep(seconds=5)
            load_more_rows = processed_batch
            print('Finished iteration at ', datetime.now())
    print('Stopped at ', datetime.now())
```

Unfortunately, instead of sleeping, waking up, and continuing to process tasks until the time is up, it just stops executing altogether, as shown in the output:

```
('Started at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 6, 206652))
('Should stop at', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 51, 6, 206630))
('Finished iteration at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 6, 356698))
('Finished iteration at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 6, 614349))
('Finished iteration at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 6, 638210))
('Finished iteration at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 6, 765645))
('Finished iteration at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 6, 885282))
('Finished iteration at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 7, 12109))
('Sleeping at ', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31, 17, 31, 7, 13803))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the code that you included what you are using?  `time.sleep()` doesn't take a keyword parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time.sleep` doesn't take a keyword argument `seconds`:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't raise an error about missing a required argument.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep

```
>>> time.sleep(seconds=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sleep() takes no keyword arguments
>>> time.sleep(1)
>>> "everything is fine"
```

Comment: That was it - removing 'seconds=' fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexC Sounds like you're hiding your errors somehow, either by swallowing them in Python code, or sending error text output somewhere it won't be seen.

Comment: @DanGetz  yes, exactly!